# Find the first sub site name in current URL

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am doing a check in current url. if my current subsite the first subsite from the root site has property. but i want to make it case insensitive so that either if it is property or Property it works fine.

Is there a better way of doing this this is my current approach..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = window.location.href;
            var host = window.location.host;

            if (url.indexOf('http://' + host + '/property') != -1) {
                $('.propertytitle').hide();
            }
            else if (url.indexOf('http://' + host + '/Property') != -1) {
                $('.propertytitle').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('propertytitle').show();
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it case insensitive, you might want to change both url and host to lower case in the first step.

```
var url = window.location.href.toLowerCase();
var host = window.location.host.toLowerCase();

if (url.indexOf('http://' + host + '/property') != -1) {
         $('.propertytitle').hide();
}
else {
         $('propertytitle').show();
}
```